# OpenGL ES 3.0 half float (R16F) textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

Can someone answer me how come this line:

```
GLES30.glTexImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,  GLES30.GL_R16F, width, height, 0,  GLES30.GL_RED, GLES30.GL_HALF_FLOAT, myBuffer);
```

works on tegra4 but doesn't work on ARM Mali-T628 MP6?

I am not attaching this to a framebuffer by the way, I am using this as a read only texture. The code returned on ARM is 1280 where Tegra 'doesn't complain' at all.

Also, I know that Tegra4 got extension for half float textures, and that specific Mali doesn't have that extension, but since it's OpenGL ES 3.0, shouldn't it support such textures?

Answer (score 1):

That call looks completely valid to me. Error 1280 is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, which suggests that one of the 3 enum type arguments is invalid. But each one by itself, as well as the combination of them, is spec compliant.

The most likely explanation is a driver bug. I found that several ES 3.0 drivers have numerous issues, so it's not a big surprise to discover problems.

---

The section below was written under the assumption that the texture would be used as a render target (FBO attachment). Please ignore if you are looking for a direct answer to the question.

---

`GL_R16F` is not color-renderable in standard ES 3.0.

If you pull up the spec document, which can be found on www.khronos.org ([direct link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/es_spec_3.0.4.pdf)), table 3.13 on pages 130-132 lists all texture formats and their properties. `R16F` does **not** have the checkmark in the "Color-renderable" column, which means that it can not be used as a render target.

Correspondingly, `R16F` is also listed under "Texture-only color formats" in section "Required Texture Formats" on pages 129-130.

This means that the device needs the [EXT_color_buffer_half_float extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_color_buffer_half_float.txt) to support rendering to `R16F`. This is still the case in ES 3.1 as well.

Comment: I wrote that "I am not attaching this to a framebuffer", I am not using this as render target. I want to use this as read-only LUT texture.

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer to rescue it as well as possible. Apologies for the initial misunderstanding.